How do I sum elements of a set in Z specification?
I'm trying to get the total of cart items in Z specification.
How can I get the total sum of elements?
I have tried using the summation ∑ (summation) but it doesn't work.

┌ Product
  name: STRING
  price: ℤ
  product_id: ℤ
|
  price > 0
└

┌ CartItem
  product: Product
  quantity: ℤ
|
  quantity > 0
└

┌ Cart
  items: ℙ CartItem
└

/* Online shop state */
┌ OnlineShopState
  cart: Cart
  products: ℙ Product
└

┌ CalculateTotal 
  ΞOnlineShopState
  total_price!: ℤ
|
 total_price! = {c: cart.items ⦁ c.product.price * c.quantity}
└ 

Here is how I have tried using summation but however the syntax is incorrect. See the image below
┌ CalculateTotal 
  ΞOnlineShopState
  total_price!: ℤ
|
 total_price! = ∑ {c: cart.items ⦁ c.product.price * c.quantity}
└


